# Which languages allow whitespace in identifiers?

Tags: programming-languages, whitespace

Which languages allow whitespace in identifiers?

Example:

```
int current index = 5
string body = fetch article(current index)
```

Comment: i didnt like this language :)

Comment: How about the whitespace language, everything is written in whitespace!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29

Comment: you're the second person to make this dumb joke... no, Whitespace doesnt allow whitespace in identifiers as Whitespace has no identifiers. Nice try though...

Comment: Ambiguity could be removed by having a quote-using syntax for identifiers:  int 'current index' = 5; string body = 'fetch article'('current index'); string 'other identifier' = "real string";

Answer (score 3):

FORTRAN, and it was a bad design decision.

For example, replacing a , by a . can transform a DO loop into an assignment.

Comment: We just talked about this famous bug in one of my classes
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariner_1#Or_was_it_the_most_expensive_decimal_point.3F

Answer (score 2):

MSSQL, MSAccess, and Oracle, if you quote identifiers correctly (using [] or "" respectively)

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace!

http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with whitespace, is that it's often used as separator between tokens. So if you allow whitespace you have to combine several tokens to one.

But it is not impossible. Two identifiers without another token are rare so you can adopt the compiler to accept this.

On the other hand, you can get hard to read code:

```
int current index = 5
int current /* in between comment */ index = 5
int current 

    index = 5
```

So I don't think the advantages beat the disadvantages.